# How to calculate the number of tie combinations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

While I am sure the answer is so simple I have forgotten, I have an ideal coin and flip it A times, where A is an even number. I am attempting to calculate number of possible outcomes with an equal number of heads and tails. For example, with A=4, I know 6 of the 16 possible outcomes can be ties. Where can I find the general formula for an arbitrary A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the number of ways to pick the locations of heads, which is$${A \choose A/2}=\frac {A!}{[(A/2)!]^2}$$  This is the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)